# Truncate string based on pixel width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a string fits in a determined area (`td`) without breaking line. The problem is: It needs to ...

- Fit while resizing
- Fit in `N` kinds of resolution
- Add `...` at the end when needed (and don't when not needed)
- Accept the change of `font-size`, `font-weight`, and `font-family`

---

Based on the answers on [Novon's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895888/truncate-text-with-jquery-based-on-pixel-width), I made the following code:

**CSS** *(// Just adding some styles to break the line)*

```
.truncated { display:inline-block; overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap; }
```

**jQuery** *(// Find all td that contains a `.truncated` element. Getting the real width (by removing the content and adding it again) of the `td`. Applying, if needed, minWidth on the `td`)*

```
jQuery('.truncated').closest('td').each(function() {
    var text = jQuery(this).text();
    var widthOriginal = jQuery(this).width();
    var widthEmpty = jQuery(this).text('').width();
    jQuery(this).text(text);
    if(widthOriginal >= widthEmpty){
        var width = (parseInt(widthEmpty) - 10) + 'px';
        jQuery(this).css('maxWidth', width);
        jQuery(this).text(text + '...');
    }
});
```

the result (as expected from the above code) is:

[image: result]

but it should be:

[image: how it should be]

---

I was thinking, maybe try to find the first `line` of the string and remove the rest but didn't find a way to do that (and it's a lot of "workaround" for my taste). Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: [This question may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700226/i-want-to-truncate-a-text-or-line-with-ellipsis-using-javascript)

Comment: Have you tried getting the available space and then dividing it with a factor based on the pixel width of the average character?

Comment: @MarcusRommel with the `var widthOriginal = jQuery(this).width();` I get the available space. How could I create this division?

Comment: @SterlingArcher the problem is that the answers on the question you linked are based on characters amount (`if (string.length > 5)`). What I need is to do it based on size (pixel).

Comment: For the division just try some divisors manually (4,5,6...) and use what fits. You then know how much characters fill one line and can cut your strings to get that long.

Comment: possible duplicate of [With CSS, use "..." for overflowed block of multi-lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222616/with-css-use-for-overflowed-block-of-multi-lines)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it with pure CSS, see this link for reference:

[line clampin](http://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/)

Add those to your css:

```
.truncated {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 1; // amount of line you want
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
}
```

Or you can try clamp.js

https://github.com/josephschmitt/Clamp.js

Comment: Could you add some source to your answer? In the case of the link breaks/changes or the information on the link is lost.

Answer (score 27):

Single line text truncation can be easily achieved using css `text-overflow` property, which is supported by all major browsers, including IE since version 6.

The thing is that `text-overflow` alone doesn't do much. It only defines what will happen **when there is** text overflowing the container. So in order to see results, we first need to make the text overflow, by forcing it to a single line. It is also important to set the `overflow` property of the container:

```
.truncated {
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap; /* forces text to single line */
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

jsFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/x95a4913/

text-overflow documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Answer (score 7):

```
text-overflow: ellipsis
```

seems a pure CSS solution
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp

Comment: Really nice approach :) Didn't knew/noticed this property on the `overflow` css style. Thanks =D

Comment: Just to point out that to make it work properly it should be `white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;`

Comment: I had no idea this existed!

Comment: **IMPORTANT:** you **must** include `white-space: nowrap` and `overflow: hidden` for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you set table layout to fixed and the `td` overflow as `hidden`, you could prepend an ellipsis as a float-right `div` when the `td`'s scroll width is greater than its client width.

Here's the CSS, which includes styles to prevent bleed-through on the table:

```
table {
  table-layout:fixed;
  white-space:nowrap;
  width:500px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border-collapse: separate;    
}

td {
  overflow:hidden;
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  padding:0px;
}

.hellip {
  padding-left:0.2em;
  float:right;
  background:white;
  position:relative;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('td').each(function() {
  if($(this)[0].scrollWidth > $(this).width()) {
    $(this).prepend('<div class="hellip"">&hellip;</div>');
  }
});
```

Demo at:  **http://jsfiddle.net/5h798ojf/3/**

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the text twice to achieve this:

```
<style type="text/css">

.relative_wrap {
    height: 1em;
    position: relative;
}

.absolute_wrap {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    top: 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

</style>


<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="relative_wrap">
                    <div class="absolute_wrap">
                            LONG TEXT HERE
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Since you use jQuery, it is easy:

```
$('.truncated').wrap('<div class="relative_wrap"><div class="absolute_wrap"></div></div>');
```